# .NET MVC Action Filter, only user clicked actions

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, action-filter

Is there any possibility to filter out only user clicked actions ("user address bar actions") in Action Filter. I want to log user activity and with every request made by user there are lot of side requests which I don't want to log.

Comment: What do you mean by "User address bar actions"?  In action filter you can retreive action name / controller / route values and etc and basing on it - continue code or return from filter without any changes/

Comment: That actions which lead to some View. Actions clicked by user in general.  In this project, there are many actions like "get language", "get this", "get that" and I want to filter this out without making If for every action name

Comment: You can create as an attribute on the controller as a  [Controller.OnActionExecuting Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting(v=vs.118).aspx) If is it used on every single page you want want to put it in the global.asax

Comment: you can create a custom attribute and put that attribute to every Actions which you want to log. At the time of logging you can identify if that action has that attribute or not. Based on the result you can do the logging.

Comment: I suggest you log within the action(or better the domain model) the specific thing you want to log. ie "user makes a purchase", "user cant log in" etc rather than attempt to match MVC actions to events.

Comment: I've decided to make custom attribute on specified actions. But maby I'll develop it to Ewan's solution.